# Is it possible for $A,B$ to have same minimal polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $A,B$ are two $n\times n$ complex matrices such that $A,B$ have the same characteristic polynomial but they have different Jordan canonical form. Then is it possible for $A,B$ to have same minimal polynomial.

I am trying to find an example but I am not getting.

Comment: This comes up here quite regularly. Hint: find $4\times 4$ matrices whose square is zero: one of rank one, and one of rank two.

Comment: Would you please give one example.

Comment: your question shows : Then **is it** possible for A,B to have same minimal polynomial.? Thats why I give example. Do you mean: Then it is......?

Comment: yes. my question is: Is there any example where we have equal minimal polynomial for both $A$, $B$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown did give you an example, almost as explicitly as he could describe it without actually typing your homework solution in for you ...

Comment: They may be different, that I know but I am trying to find for equality case

Answer (score 2):

These two will work. 
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: There we are! $A^2=B^2=O$, $A$ has rank one and $B$ has rank two.

Answer (score 0):

General approach: for each eigenvalue$~\lambda$ the characteristic polynomial gives (in the form of the multiplicity of the root$~\lambda$) the sum of the Jordan blocks for$~\lambda$, while the minimal polynomial gives (in the form of the multiplicity of the root$~\lambda$) the largest Jordan block for$~\lambda$. It is quite obvious that these two informations are not enough in general to determine the size of all Jordan blocks.

For a concrete example, one may as well assume there is only one eigenvalue$~\lambda$, which we can take to be zero so as to be talking about nilpotent matrices only. Now suppose the characteristic polynomial is $X^n$ and minimal polynomial is $X^m$, so the largest Jordan block has size $m$ and the remaining blocks have total size $n-m$. We are looking for two different partitions of the number $n-m$ into parts at most$~m$. The smallest example of two different partition of the same number is $(2)$ and $(1,1)$ as partitions of $2$, so the smallest example has $n-m=2$ and $m=2$, and so $n=4$; the full partitions are $(2,2)$ and $(2,1,1$). But any pair of partitions of a same number gives many examples: if they don't already have the same largest part, prefix both with a part at least as large as the largest of their parts. For instance $(3,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are distinct partitions of $4$, and by tacking on initial parts $5$ we get two different partitions $(5,3,1)$ and $(5,2,2)$ of $9$ with the same largest part.